# Getting an error unable to find vcvarsall.bat while installing mysql-python in visual studio 2013 express

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to install mysql-python (version 3.4) package in VS 2013 express. I am getting this error message:

Running setup.py install for mysql-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat.

I have VC++ 2010/2012 Redistributable installed on Windows 7. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for VS 2013 Express, but `vcvarsall.bat` was not included in VS2008 Express. I found it in the SDK 6.1 which seemed to be compatible with the versions of Python I use (2.7). It seems that Python 3.4 is itself built with the tools from [SDK version 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138).